# How to create branch type layout which should be rotatable android?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-listview

Hi i need to create branch type layout which should get rotate and also contains image in it. I surfed in net but I couldn't get such type of resource to do. Please guide me how to proceed..

I have attached [screenshot.](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=1e389e1)

Since I have less reputation, I couldn't attach screenshot here.

How to create such type of layout with centered one followed by branches which rotates and also clickable to move to next activity.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks.